# how to implement recommender on android studio

Tags: recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

I want to build a recommendations system for the application of Android Studio
Such as YouTube and Amazon where the user shows things that matter to him
What is the method or tool used?

Answer (score 0):

The recommender is a big-data application running in a cluster, in the case of large e-commerce data. So you would put the recommender in your data center and ask it for recommendations from your android device. It is not likely that you can make is run on the device since the device does not have access to all data from all users, which is needed for collaborative filtering.

Maybe the easiest is to use [Apache PredictionIO](http://predictionio.apache.org/) in your data center with the [Universal Recommender](http://actionml.com/universal-recommender) ,a PIO Template based on Mahout. But put a proxy between it and the device because you need authentication and TLS. You would send data from all devices to the PIO service and make queries from the device. That way the service has all data from all users and can calculate the recommender model.

[There is an AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01N310FF0) for a fully running system here that is ok for experiments but may need to be scaled for largish data.